# 403 - disallowed_useragent - Webview based Browser for Android TV

Tags: android, browser, webview, android-webview, google-oauth

I am getting disallowed_useragent in the Webview based Browser developed for bigger screens. I am getting 403 - disallowed_useragent.

User Agent:
Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; 6.0.1; SM-J700F Build/MMB29K; wv) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/65.0.3325.109 Large Screen Safari/537.36 JioBrowser/1.0.215

I found many articles but most of the pointed to only the cutom Tabs and stand alone Webview apps.

Help me to solve this?

Comment: any luck with this issue?

Comment: User Agent: Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; 6.0.1; SM-J700F Build/MMB29K; (wv) - Removed this and it worked) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Version/4.0 Chrome/65.0.3325.109 Large Screen Safari/537.36 JioBrowser/1.0.215

Answer (score 2):

You can make a `WebView` mitigate this issue by setting a custom user agent.

```
public static final String USER_AGENT = "Mozilla/5.0 (Linux; Android 4.1.1; Galaxy Nexus Build/JRO03C) AppleWebKit/535.19 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/18.0.1025.166 Mobile Safari/535.19";
....
....
....
webView.getSettings().setUserAgentString(USER_AGENT);
```

Anyone still looking for answer, this will work like a charm.

Comment: a side note - google will report that you have logged in from a galaxy nexus, regardless of what device you actually use. You could probably massage the UA string to reflect whatever device your user is on